# Power BI date table creation issue

Tags: powerbi

I created a date column in the power BI using below query. But it gives me an error message as: The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to scalar value.

```
Date = ADDCOLUMNS (Calendar (Date (2021,01,01), Date (2030,12,30)),"DateAsInteger", FORMAT([DATE], "YYYYMMDD"), "Year", YEAR([Date]), 
"YearMonthNumber", Format([Date],"YYYY/MM"), "MonthNameShort", FORMAT([Date],"mmm"),"MonthNameLong", FORMAT([Date],"mmmm"),
"Quarter" & FORMAT([Date],"Q"), "YearQuarter", FORMAT([Date], "YYYY" & "/Q" & FORMAT([Date],"Q")), 
"Monthnumber", Format([Date],"MM"),"DayofWeekNumber", WEEKDAY([Date]), "DayofWeek", Format([Date],"dddd"), "DayofWeekShort", FORMAT([Date], "ddd"))
```

But I want the date data to be represented by year, month, quarter and all the means as per the query.

Comment: Which do you want to create, a date table or a date column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DAX formula creates a Date table. Also, I fixed a minor issue in your formula.

```
Date = ADDCOLUMNS (Calendar (Date (2021,01,01), Date (2030,12,30)),"DateAsInteger", FORMAT([DATE], "YYYYMMDD"), "Year", YEAR([Date]), 
"YearMonthNumber", Format([Date],"YYYY/MM"), "MonthNameShort", FORMAT([Date],"mmm"),"MonthNameLong", FORMAT([Date],"mmmm"),
"Quarter", FORMAT([Date],"Q"), "YearQuarter", FORMAT([Date], "YYYY" & "/Q" & FORMAT([Date],"Q")), 
"Monthnumber", Format([Date],"MM"),"DayofWeekNumber", WEEKDAY([Date]), "DayofWeek", Format([Date],"dddd"), "DayofWeekShort", FORMAT([Date], "ddd"))
```

[image]

Comment: @ M.P. I used the same sytanx like yours, but it shows that the dataset with date column give the issue as The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to scalar value. I am trying to paste the screenshot but not able to do so here. Could you let me know how to do here?

Comment: @RockRock: Check my screenshot, pls. You should click the "New table" button (Red rectangle in my screenshot) and then write the DAX formula.

Comment: I created from the Power BI desktop. itself.

Comment: Yes, it is created from the Power BI desktop itself. I updated my screenshot so that you can understand it on the Power BI desktop. Check it.